# Control excessive outbound traffic

Tags: linux, networking, script, udp

Ubuntu server is sending outbound request excessively. I am not sure why this happening.

Following is the output I am getting for tcpdump

```
root@demotrt:~# tcpdump -n -n port 53
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
04:41:30.345235 IP 45.33.119.111.56543 > 198.58.107.5.53: 56299+ A? jorgee3.pokemoninc.com.members.linode.com. (59)
04:41:30.345493 IP 198.58.107.5.53 > 45.33.119.111.56543: 56299 NXDomain* 0/0/0 (59)
04:41:30.345557 IP 45.33.119.111.46290 > 198.58.107.5.53: 56300+ A? jorgee3.pokemoninc.com. (40)
04:41:30.345813 IP 198.58.107.5.53 > 45.33.119.111.46290: 56300 NXDomain 0/1/0 (100)
04:41:30.345873 IP 45.33.119.111.48219 > 198.58.107.5.53: 56301+ A? jorgee3.pokemoninc.com.members.linode.com. (59)
04:41:30.346173 IP 198.58.107.5.53 > 45.33.119.111.48219: 56301 NXDomain* 0/0/0 (59)
04:41:30.346316 IP 45.33.119.111.54934 > 198.58.107.5.53: 56302+ A? jorgee3.pokemoninc.com. (40)
04:41:30.346546 IP 198.58.107.5.53 > 45.33.119.111.54934: 56302 NXDomain 0/1/0 (100)
04:41:30.346601 IP 45.33.119.111.52024 > 198.58.107.5.53: 56303+ A? jorgee3.pokemoninc.com.members.linode.com. (59)
04:41:30.346860 IP 198.58.107.5.53 > 45.33.119.111.52024: 56303 NXDomain* 0/0/0 (59)
04:41:30.346914 IP 45.33.119.111.58311 > 198.58.107.5.53: 56304+ A? jorgee3.pokemoninc.com. (40)
04:41:30.347158 IP 198.58.107.5.53 > 45.33.119.111.58311: 56304 NXDomain 0/1/0 (100)
04
```

I think something is not correct with the port 53.

Another uncommon think I have notice is, port is keep changing.

```
root@demotrt:~# netstat -apn|grep -w 53
udp        0      0 45.33.119.111:60095     198.58.107.5:53         ESTABLISHED -               
root@demotrt:~# netstat -apn|grep -w 53
udp        0      0 45.33.119.111:45498     198.58.107.5:53         ESTABLISHED -               
root@demotrt:~# netstat -apn|grep -w 53
udp        0      0 45.33.119.111:44618     198.58.107.5:53         ESTABLISHED -               
root@demotrt:~# netstat -apn|grep -w 53
udp        0      0 45.33.119.111:33521     198.58.107.5:53         ESTABLISHED -
```

How can I stop these requests? 
How can I control outbound excessive traffic?

Comment: Those are DNS requests. It’s also normal that the local endpoint changes for successive outgoing connections. You should try and identify the application that makes those DNS requests.

Answer (score 0):

It is dns lookups. There nothing wrong with src port number changing. You should investigate which program do it, with

```
$ sudo lsof -i | grep domain
```

for example and why it needs to resolve jorgee3.pokemoninc.com.members.linode.com so frequently.

If it is supposed to do it, you probably should use some dns local-caching demon, such as nscd.